# How to convert generator or iterator to list recursively

Tags: python, recursion, iterator, generator, immutability

I want to convert generator or iterator to list recursively.
I wrote a code in below, but it looks naive and ugly, and may be dropped case in doctest.

Q1. Help me good version. 
Q2. How to specify object is immutable or not?

```
import itertools

def isiterable(datum):
    return hasattr(datum, '__iter__')

def issubscriptable(datum):
    return hasattr(datum, "__getitem__")

def eagerlize(obj):
    """ Convert generator or iterator to list recursively.
    return a eagalized object of given obj.
    This works but, whether it return a new object, break given one.

    test 1.0 iterator

    >>> q = itertools.permutations('AB',  2)
    >>> eagerlize(q)
    [('A', 'B'), ('B', 'A')]
    >>>

    test 2.0 generator in list

    >>> q = [(2**x for x in range(3))]
    >>> eagerlize(q)
    [[1, 2, 4]]
    >>>

    test 2.1 generator in tuple

    >>> q = ((2**x for x in range(3)),)
    >>> eagerlize(q)
    ([1, 2, 4],)
    >>>

    test 2.2 generator in tuple in generator

    >>> q = (((x, (y for y in range(x, x+1))) for x in range(3)),)
    >>> eagerlize(q)
    ([(0, [0]), (1, [1]), (2, [2])],)
    >>>

    test 3.0 complex test

    >>> def test(r):
    ...     for x in range(3):
    ...         r.update({'k%s'%x:x})
    ...         yield (n for n in range(1))
    >>>
    >>> def creator():
    ...     r = {}
    ...     t = test(r)
    ...     return r, t
    >>>
    >>> a, b = creator()
    >>> q = {'b' : a, 'a' : b}
    >>> eagerlize(q)
    {'a': [[0], [0], [0]], 'b': {'k2': 2, 'k1': 1, 'k0': 0}}
    >>>

    test 3.1 complex test (other dict order)

    >>> a, b = creator()
    >>> q = {'b' : b, 'a' : a}
    >>> eagerlize(q)
    {'a': {'k2': 2, 'k1': 1, 'k0': 0}, 'b': [[0], [0], [0]]}
    >>>

    test 4.0 complex test with tuple

    >>> a, b = creator()
    >>> q = {'b' : (b, 10), 'a' : (a, 10)}
    >>> eagerlize(q)
    {'a': ({'k2': 2, 'k1': 1, 'k0': 0}, 10), 'b': ([[0], [0], [0]], 10)}
    >>>

    test 4.1 complex test with tuple (other dict order)

    >>> a, b = creator()
    >>> q = {'b' : (b, 10), 'a' : (a, 10)}
    >>> eagerlize(q)
    {'a': ({'k2': 2, 'k1': 1, 'k0': 0}, 10), 'b': ([[0], [0], [0]], 10)}
    >>>

    """
    def loop(obj):
        if isiterable(obj):
            for k, v in obj.iteritems() if isinstance(obj, dict) \
                         else enumerate(obj):
                if isinstance(v, tuple):
                    # immutable and iterable object must be recreate, 
                    # but realy only tuple?
                    obj[k] = tuple(eagerlize(list(obj[k])))
                elif issubscriptable(v):
                    loop(v)
                elif isiterable(v):
                    obj[k] = list(v)
                    loop(obj[k])

    b = [obj]
    loop(b)
    return b[0]

def _test():
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()

if __name__=="__main__":
    _test()
```

Comment: Does it have to be a recursive solution? Why?

Comment: Try to avoid lines longer that 80 chars. It's very uncomfortable to read code when you must use horizontal scroll.

Comment: Thanks, David
Because I didn't notice.
So, How about loop solution?

Answer (score 5):

To avoid badly affecting the original object, you basically need a variant of `copy.deepcopy`... subtly tweaked because you need to turn generators and iterators into lists (deepcopy wouldn't deep-copy generators anyway).  Note that *some* effect on the original object is unfortunately inevitable, because generators and iterators are "exhausted" as a side effect of iterating all the way on them (be it to turn them into lists or for any other purpose) -- therefore, there is simply no way you can *both* leave the original object alone *and* have that generator or other iterator turned into a list in the "variant-deepcopied" result.

The `copy` module is unfortunately not written to be customized, so the alternative ares, either copy-paste-edit, or a subtle (sigh) monkey-patch hinging on (double-sigh) the private module variable `_deepcopy_dispatch` (which means your patched version might not survive a Python version upgrade, say from 2.6 to 2.7, hypothetically).  Plus, the monkey-patch would have to be uninstalled after each use of your `eagerize` (to avoid affecting other uses of `deepcopy`). So, let's assume we pick the copy-paste-edit route instead.

Say we start with the most recent version, the one that's online [here](http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/Lib/copy.py?annotate=76571).  You need to rename module, of course; rename the externally visible function `deepcopy` to `eagerize` at line 145; the substantial change is at lines 161-165, which in said version, annotated, are:

```
161 :               copier = _deepcopy_dispatch.get(cls)
162 :               if copier:
163 :                   y = copier(x, memo)
164 :               else:
165 :   tim_one 18729           try:
```

We need to insert between line 163 and 164 the logic "otherwise if it's iterable expand it to a list (i.e., use the function `_deepcopy_list` as the copier".  So these lines become:

```
161 :               copier = _deepcopy_dispatch.get(cls)
162 :               if copier:
163 :                   y = copier(x, memo)
                     elif hasattr(cls, '__iter__'):
                         y = _deepcopy_list(x, memo)
164 :               else:
165 :   tim_one 18729           try:
```

That's all: just there two added lines.  Note that I've left the original line numbers alone to make it perfectly clear *where* exactly these two lines need to be inserted, and not numbered the two new lines.  You also need to rename other instances of identifier `deepcopy` (indirect recursive calls) to `eagerize`.

You should also remove lines 66-144 (the shallow-copy functionality that you don't care about) and appropriately tweak lines 1-65 (docstrings, imports, `__all__`, etc).

Of course, you want to work off a copy of the *plaintext* version of `copy.py`, [here](http://svn.python.org/view/*checkout*/python/trunk/Lib/copy.py?revision=76571&content-type=text/plain), not the annotated version I've been referring to (I used the annotated version just to clarify exactly where the changes were needed!-).

Comment: Wow, we're lucky to have you here Alex!

Comment: Thanks, It's grate idea alex. It's realy helped.
I tested it and deepcopy works grate, but test 3.x 4.x fails.
because generator test(r) has side effects to dict r.
Very sorry for confusing expression at the top of docstring.
I need side effects. dict r must be changed.