# Recycling operations in Python similar to R vectorization

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm attempting to learn more about Python functionality by translating R code while noting the different approaches. There's a recycling rule in R concatenation, if the strings are multiples of each other the evaluator will recycle the smaller object to match the length of the larger. Here's an example:

```
lttrs <- c("A", "B", "C")
lbl <- "pct"
users <- c(1,2)
```

If I wanted to combine these three objects to get `"Apct1" "Bpct1" "Cpct1" "Apct2" "Bpct2" "Cpct2"`. I can repeat the last object `users` to twice the length of the first and R will figure out the rest:

```
user_indx <- rep(users, each=length(lttrs))
paste0(lttrs, lbl, user_indx)
#[1] "Apct1" "Bpct1" "Cpct1" "Apct2" "Bpct2" "Cpct2"
```

I have been able to translate the `rep(users, each=length(lttrs))` call:

```
import numpy as np
lttrs = ['A', 'B', 'C']
lbl = ['pct']
users = [1,2]
print np.repeat(users, len(lttrs))
[1 1 1 2 2 2]
```

I'm struggling to move forward from there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like what you want is [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product), which gives the product of iterables.

```
from itertools import product
lttrs = ['A', 'B', 'C']
lbl = ['pct']
users = [1,2]
combine = []
for p in product(lttrs, lbl, map(str, users)):
    combine.append(''.join(p))
```

Comment: Would you have to use `join` to get the final output `["Apct1" "Bpct1" "Cpct1" "Apct2" "Bpct2" "Cpct2"]`?

Comment: @PierreLafortune Yes, or you could manually concatenate. Note that any list that doesn't contain strings has to be converted (here I used `map`)

Comment: Thank you. It still gives the output with `print` and not `list`. If I am saving this output for use in further operations, how can I save the output to a new variable?

Comment: @PierreLafortune `p = product(...)` saves as generator

Comment: This is helpful, but it is still not the desired output. I am looking for a list object like `lst = ["Apct1" "Bpct1" "Cpct1" "Apct2" "Bpct2" "Cpct2"]`. Will I have to use generator to list conversions like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177442/how-to-convert-generator-or-iterator-to-list-recursively?

Comment: @PierreLafortune `list(p)`

Comment: That separates the elements into tuples `[('A', 'pct', '1'), ('A', 'pct', '2')..`. I appreciate your assistance and understand what it's like to answer questions for new people, I did that in R, but the output cannot yet be used as list elements. The desired output once more is `lst = ["Apct1" "Bpct1" "Cpct1" "Apct2" "Bpct2" "Cpct2"]`

Comment: @PierreLafortune One solution is given

Comment: @PierreLafortune: You could also use `list(map(''.join, product(lttrs, lbl, map(str, users))))`. The `list` is not necessary in Python2.7, but would be necessary (to obtain a list) in Python3.