# Python equivalent of (matrix)*(vector) in R

Tags: python, r, numpy, matrix, vector

In R, when I execute the code below:

```
> X=matrix(1,2,3)
> c=c(1,2,3)
> X*c
```

R gives out the following output:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    3    2
[2,]    2    1    3
```

But when I do the below on Python:

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> X=np.array([[1,1,1],[1,1,1]]) 
>>> c=np.array([1,2,3])
>>> X*c
```

the Python code above gives the following output:

```py
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3]])
```

Is there any way that I can make the Python to come up with the identical output as R? I think I somehow have to tell Python that I want the numpy to multiply each element of the matrix `X` by each element of the vector `c` along the column, instead of along the row, but I am not sure how to go about this.

Comment: In `R`, you are recycling the vector 'c' .  It is doing the recycling columnwise

Comment: Yes, but is there any way that I can obtain the same output from Python (for given matrix X and a vector c)?

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33896309/recycling-operations-in-python-similar-to-r-vectorization) may help

Comment: @akrun thank you for the link. What would be the itertools --> product equivalent for Python numpy? Does this even exist for Python numpy?

Comment: How does work with 2 length 3 arrays produce a (2,3) result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am the OP.
I was looking for a quick and easy solution, but I guess there is no straightforward functionality in Python that allows us to do this. So, I had to make a function that multiplies a matrix with a vector in the same manner that R does:

```py
def R_product(X,c):

"""
Computes the regular R product 
(not same as the matrix product) between 
a 2D Numpy Array X, and a numpy vector c.

Args:
   X: 2D Numpy Array
   c: A Numpy vector

Returns: the output of X*c in R. 
         (This is different than X/*/c in R)
"""
    X_nrow = X.shape[0]
    X_ncol = X.shape[1]
    X_dummy = np.zeros(shape=((X_nrow * X_ncol),1))
    nrow = X_dummy.shape[0]
    nc = nrow // len(c)
    Y = np.zeros(shape=(nrow,1))

    for j in range(X_ncol):
        for u in range(X_nrow):
            X_element = X[u,j]
                
            if u == X_nrow - 1:
                idx = X_nrow * (j+1) - 1 
            else:
                idx = X_nrow * j + (u+1) - 1
                    
            X_dummy[idx,0] = X_element

    for i in range(nc):
        for j in range(len(c)):
            Y[(i*len(c)+j):(i*len(c)+j+1),:] = (X_dummy[(i*len(c)+j):(i*len(c)+j+1),:]) * c[j]
     
    for z in range(nrow-nc*len(c)):
        Y[(nc*len(c)+z):(nc*len(c)+z+1),:] = (X_dummy[(nc*len(c)+z):(nc*len(c)+z+1),:]) * c[z]

    return Y.reshape(X_ncol, X_nrow).transpose() # the answer I am looking for
```

Should work.

Comment: Same `X` and `c` that I described in the original post....I am pretty sure it also works for any arbitrary X and c..Here, X stands for 2D Numpy Array, and c is a numpy vector

Comment: I was testing your function before final edit.  How common is this way of replicating an array to match another?  It isn't normal in `numpy`, though as I show isn't hard.  I'd suggest learning `broadcasting` well instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [18]: np.reshape([1,2,3]*2,(2,3),order='F')                                  
Out[18]: 
array([[1, 3, 2],
       [2, 1, 3]])
```

This starts with a list multiply, which is replication:

```
In [19]: [1,2,3]*2                                                              
Out[19]: [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
```

The rest uses `numpy` to reshape it into a (2,3) array, but with consecutive values going down, 'F' order.

Not knowning `R`, and in particular the `c(1,2,3)` expression, I can't say that's what's going on in `R`.

===

You talk about rows with columns, but I don't see how that works in your example.  That said, we can easily perform `outer` like products

===

This reproduces your `R_Product` (at least in a few test cases):

```
In [138]: def foo(X,c): 
     ...:     X1 = X.ravel() 
     ...:     Y = np.resize(c,X1.shape)*X1 
     ...:     return Y.reshape(X.shape, order='F') 
     ...:                                                                       
In [139]: foo(np.ones((2,3)),np.arange(1,4))                                    
Out[139]: 
array([[1., 3., 2.],
       [2., 1., 3.]])
In [140]: foo(np.arange(6).reshape(2,3),np.arange(1,4))                         
Out[140]: 
array([[ 0,  6,  8],
       [ 2,  3, 15]])
```

I'm using the `resize` function to replicate `c` to match the total number of elements of `X`.  And `order F` to stack them in the desired column order.  The default for `numpy` is order C.

In `numpy` replicating an array to match another is not common, at least not in this sense.  Replicating by row or column, as in broadcasting is common.  And of course reshaping.